# MySQL join 3 tables and counting another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a blog that has an article that can have tags and comments. I want to try and get the right SQL to get it one query.
I have 4 tables:

```
article
+------------+-----------------+------------+
| article_id | title           | photo      |
+------------+-----------------+------------+
|          1 | This is a test  | image1.jpg |
|          2 | Another Article | image2.jpg |
+------------+-----------------+------------+


article_tag
+------------+--------+ 
| article_id | tag_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      1 | 
|          1 |      2 | 
|          2 |      2 |
+------------+--------+

tags
+--------+------+ 
| tag_id | name |
+--------+------+ 
|      1 | tag1 |
|      2 | tag2 |
+--------+------+

comment
+------+---------+------------+
| name | message | article_id |
+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | hello   |          1 |
|    2 | a       |          2 |
+------+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
+------------+----------------+------------+---------+----------+
| article_id | title          | photo      | tag_ids | comments |
+------------+----------------+------------+---------+----------+
|          1 | This is a test | image1.jpg | 1,2     |        1 |
+------------+----------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.photo, a.date, a.description_long, a.author, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) as `tag_ids`, COUNT(c.comment_id) as comments
FROM article as a
JOIN article_tag as at
ON a.article_id = at.article_id
LEFT JOIN comment as c
ON a.article_id = c.article_id
WHERE a.article_id = 1
```

But I'm getting comments as 2 instead of 1?
Thank you
PS If anybody knows of a way so that I can change tag_ids from 1,2 to tag1,tag2 that would be amazing :-)

Comment: There's no column called `comment_id` in your comment table...

Comment: count distinct, it returns 2 line because of the join with article tag

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that in the question. But I do have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that there is more than 1 tags, so 2 rows are generated.

Try COUNT(DISTINCT c.comment_id). This will only count the distinct comment IDs, so the duplicate ones won't be counted twice.

To get the tag names, do a left join with the tags table. Then GROUP_CONCAT with the name column, instead of the tag_id column.

Here's what it should be:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.photo, a.date, a.description_long, a.author, GROUP_CONCAT(d.name) AS `tag_names`, COUNT( DISTINCT c.comment_id ) AS comments
FROM article as a
JOIN article_tag as at
ON a.article_id = at.article_id
LEFT JOIN comment as c
ON a.article_id = c.article_id
LEFT JOIN tags d ON at.tag_id = d.tag_id
WHERE a.article_id = 1
```

Comment: Btw, if you want to have this information for multiple articles at a time, replace the WHERE clause with GROUP BY a.article_id

Comment: Thank you that work. I had to DISTINCT to GROUP_CONCAT(d.name)
Amazing :-)

Answer (score 1):

The tags and comments are independent.  So, if you have three tags and two comments, you'll get 6 rows in the combination.

The easiest way to fix this query in MySQL is to do a group by and use distinct in the select:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.photo, a.date, a.description_long, a.author,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct tag_id) as `tag_ids`, COUNT(distinct c.comment_id) as comments
FROM article a JOIN
     article_tag as at
     ON a.article_id = at.article_id LEFT JOIN
     comment c
     ON a.article_id = c.article_id
WHERE a.article_id = 1
group by a.article_id
```

I would say, though, that the "proper" way to fix the query is to fix the join.  This uses subqueries in the `from`:

```
from . . .
     (select article_id, group_concat(tag_id) as tags
      from tags
      group by article_id
     ) at
     . . .
     (select article_id, count(*) as numComments
      from comments
      group by article_id
     ) c
     . . .
```